# Como exibir arquivos sem underline?

Tags: php

Preciso exibir imagens em elementos `img` do HTML usando como valor do atributo 'src' o endereço do arquivo recuperado através da função `glob()`.

O problema é que não dá certo com endereços de arquivo sem *underline*.

```
$arquivos = glob("img/*.*");     

for ( $i = 0; $i < count($arquivos); $i++ ) {           

    $num = $arquivos[$i];                       


    //não exibe a imagem, por quê?
    echo "<img src=". $num .">";


    //quando coloco o nome do arquivo direto funciona:
    echo "<img src='img/criança com bolo.jpg'>";

 }
```

Comment: Boa noite @Nilson, alguma das respostas lhe resolveu o problema?

Comment: Boa noite, gostaria de saber se alguma das respostas lhe ajudou, se não por favor comente o que acha que falta.

Answer (score 3):

O problema não é com o PHP é com o HTML, faltou você adicionar `img/` e usar aspas no atributo.

Recomendo que usa `'` (apostrofos) no PHP e aspas no html, deve ficar algo como:

```
echo '<img src="img/'. $num . '">';
```

Uma dica urls necessitam serem codificadas pra funcionarem *"melhor"*, use `rawurlencode` assim:

```
$arquivos = glob("img/*.*");

for ( $i = 0; $i < count($arquivos); $i++ ) {
     $num = $arquivos[$i];
     echo '<img src="img/'. rawurlencode($num) . '">';
 }
```

Leia:

- http://php.net/manual/en/function.rawurlencode.php
- http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc3986.html

Answer (score 1):

Sempre que for manipular arquivos, os nomes destes devem estar sem caracteres especiais, com underline ou sem espaços. Você usou **criança com bolo.jpg** e em algum momento no método *glob();* o programa não compreendeu o nome do arquivo por causa da cedilha ou espaços.

Answer (score 0):

O ideal é não ter espaços e caracteres especiais em nomes de arquivos. Você pode tratar isso no envio do arquivo.

No seu caso, para arquivos que já estão no servidor você pode utilizar a função str_replace() para substituir os espaços por %20

```
echo str_replace(' ', '%20', 'img/criança com bolo.jpg');
```

vai resultar em:

```
img/criança%20com%20bolo.jpg
```

e vai se tornar acessivel.

Answer (score 0):

```
  //não exibe a imagem, por quê?
    echo "<img src=". $num .">";
```

O resultado disso será

```
<img src=criança com bolo.jpg>
```

O HTML interpretará o final do arquivo no primeiro caracter de espaço:

```
<img src=criança >
```

Obviamente, como esse nome não existe, retorna imagem inexistente. Além disso, falta definir o diretório. `img/`

Na versão na qual você escreveu diretamente, você inseriu as aspas delimitadoras e diretório:

```
//quando coloco o nome do arquivo direto funciona:
echo "<img src='img/criança com bolo.jpg'>";
```

Isso resulta em `<img src='img/criança com bolo.jpg'>`

Devido as aspas, o interpretador HTML entende que deve ler o nome do arquivo até a aspa de fechamento.

Para resolver, adicione as aspas delimitadoras e o caminho correto:

```
echo "<img src='img/". $num ."'>";
```

São regras básicas do HTML. O PHP em si não tem relação alguma. Mas é comum confundirmos essas misturas com linguagens.

Caso queira usar aspas duplas no HTML, apenas inverta, usando aspas simples no PHP:

```
echo '<img src="img/'.$num.'">';
```

*No PHP, recomenda-se o uso de aspas simples para delimitar as strings.
As aspas duplas possuem uma finalidade específica para o compilador,o  que consome um pouco mais de recursos (memória, processador, etc).

Quanto ao uso de URLEncode, se faz desnecessário, pois o próprio browser faz a conversão, exceto browsers muito antigos de mais de 10 anos atrás.

Exemplo prático, acesse a seguinte URL:

```
http://www.amazon.co.jp/タイムセール/b/ref=nav_topnav_deals?ie=UTF8&node=2221688051
```

É uma página do Amazon Japan. Note o katakana na URL. 
A finalidade do termo em japonês é para SEO.

Imagine se usar urlencode ou rawurlencode, veja como ficaria:

```
http://www.amazon.co.jp/%E3%82%BF%E3%82%A4%E3%83%A0%E3%82%BB%E3%83%BC%E3%83%AB/b/ref=nav_topnav_deals?ie=UTF8&node=2221688051
```

Horrível.. estragou a URL.. "estragou o SEO" dessa página.

Em browsers mais antigos, de 2003 ou 2004 em diante, os caracteres multibyte serão automaticamente convertidos com os seus respectivos entities, isso inclui caracteres latinos.

Como mencionei em outras discussões a respeito de encodes, o desenvolvedor precisa ter uma visão globalizada para construir uma plataforma internacionalizada. A vasta maioria dos developers constroem sistemas localizados e muitos pensam que seus sistemas são globais e na verdade não são.

Evitei comentar aqui nesse tópico pois achei desnecessário e desvirtuaria o foco principal da pergunta, mas enfim, espero ter deixado mais claro.

Comment: Não quero discordar de ti, mas existem alguns browsers mobile, como o Safari que interpretam diferente, alguns usam utf8 e outros usam compativeis com ASCII. O `urlencode` ou `rawurlencode` pode ajuda sim. ;)

Comment: não entendi a discordância.. não postei dizendo que browsers não suportam multibyte na barra da url... obviamente, os mais recentes suportam.. o problema é com browsers mais antigos.  Adicionei um exemplo prático na resposta, para ficar mais claro.

Comment: Acho que não me expressei direito, você disse que o `urlencode` é desnecessário e eu falei o motivo da necessidade que ainda existe sim... Agora se começar a falar de SEO, então o melhor é mudar todo o esquema da url, começando por não usar espaços e sim hifens, mas este não parece ser o foco do problema do AP.

Comment: É desnecessário converter o caracter de espaço para seu respectivo entitie, pois mesmo sem o encode, o browser converte automaticamente.. e isso independe de questões de SEO.. mas de qualquer forma, o melhor jeito é manter um padrão mais seguro, sem espaçamentos, mesmo para SEO..  Obviamente estou desconsiderando browsers de 1900 e bolinha..  é um público irrelevante mesmo para serviços de grande  porte.

Comment: Daniel o Safari mobile do ios8.3 foi um navegador que já enfrentei tal problema, acho que já citei isto.

Comment: mostre isso na pratica, referente ao safari do ios 8.3.

Comment: Caramba você acha que estou mentido? Pra que eu iria querer jogar uma informação falsa aqui? A tarde providencio um test-case para tentar confirmar o problema.

Comment: calma.. ô loco... kkk.. é vc que está interpretando dessa forma.. em nenhum momento usei adjetivo algum ou fiz insinuações.... Apenas entenda que é muito vago dizer que viu X algum dia, que viu Y outra vez lá não sei quando.. entende? então apenas mostre 1 + 1 = 2..  Que bobagem ficar aqui nesse bate boca desnecessário.. caramba digo eu.. srsrsr